# Linux Mint. Installing bdf fonts with console (fc-cache/fc-list)

Tags: linux, fonts, linux-mint

I found an interesting font on GitHub. And it even had an [instullation guide](https://github.com/lucy/tewi-font#installation).
So I use **fc-cache -fv** and it displays processing on directory with my files:

```
...
/home/my_profile_name/.fonts: caching, new cache contents: 8 fonts, 0 dirs
...
```

But then I try to find this fonts with **fc-list | grep '.*[T,t]ew.*'** and it returns nothing. And there's no "Tewi" (the name of font) in GUI applications font-selection menus as well.

What am I doing wrong? How can I add font to system with console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I found an answer.

In fact I've not mentioned in my question, that my font was in **.bdf** formate. So, the question was not fully informative in it's first version.

In Ubuntu (and distributives based on it) bitmapped fonts are disabled by default.

If you wont to enable it, you can find it interesting to read [this short article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts#Enabling_Bitmapped_Fonts) from Ubuntu Wiki. Or you can just execute this commands:

```
cd /etc/fonts/conf.d/
sudo rm /etc/fonts/conf.d/10*  
sudo rm -rf 70-no-bitmaps.conf 
sudo ln -s ../conf.avail/70-yes-bitmaps.conf .
sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Debian Bookworm, and even after enabling bitmap fonts, it did not work.  I had to wrap the `.bdf` bitmap fonts with a TrueType wrapper using freedesktop's `fonttosfnt` utility before they appeared in my font manager.  Perhaps a different bitmap format would have also worked?

```
fonttosfnt -v -c -o myfont.ttf myfont.bdf
```